# Android Facebook sdk v4.x Build Error: Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a problem with new Facebook SDK 4.1.0
After studying OffTutorial, where i need to include in build.grable next lines

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
}
```

My project successfully built and started *WITHOUT* line compile ***'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'***.

BUT! when I include this line, when project is building, i get next error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Users/macintoshhd/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.0/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

===
Here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ukrinsoft.petition"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Comment: Why are you using jar files instead of maven dependencies?

Comment: ??? I do everything as described in Official docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#login_share . One thing - problem happens in existing big project that i need to update with this new FB sdk. When I created another empty project only for test sdk, linking was OK.

Comment: I am referring to support-v4.jar and nineoldandroids.